# c++ template typename inherit

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I am trying to create my STL class, but I encounter some difficulties.
I want to write a parent class inherited by two other class. And the parent class can get child class' type from template argument. Like the example code below.

When I compiled my codes with VS2013, I got some compile errors, C4430, C2868, C2602, C2146, C2039.

```
template<class Child>
class Base
{
public:
    typedef typename Child::value_type value_type;
};

class Child_A : public Base<Child_A>
{
    typedef double value_type;
};

class Child_B : public Base<Child_B>
{
    typedef float value_type;
};

int main(){
    Child_A ch_a;
    Child_B ch_b;
}
```

I know that one way to make it work is putting children's value_type into parent's template field, but I don't like to do that. It will make my codes a little complex.

Is there any other method to solve this problem?

List of errors:

> C2039:'value_type' : is not a member of 'Child_A'
>
> C2602:'Base::value_type' is not a member of a base class of 'Base'
>
> C2868:'Base::value_type' : illegal syntax for using-declaration; expected qualified-name

Comment: Please post the actual error text.  We should not have to go look up those error messages to find out what is your issue.

Comment: Thank everybody. I didn't find any answer after searching with wrong key words. I decide to solve my problem using the answer in the question, "C++ static polymorphism (CRTP) and using typedefs from derived classes".